# Why is the function heads not implemented in List

Tags: scala

I wonder if there is a "functional programming" reason for the function `heads` not to be  implemented in List (or more generally in [TraversableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike)). To me, `heads` would be the exact opposite of `tails` but I must miss something.

As Scala is easy to read, here is what I would see (for the `List` case):

```
def heads[T](li:List[T]):List[List[T]] = li match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head::tail => (Nil::heads(tail)).map(head::_)
}
```

So, here are the few possibilities I have thought of for this function not to be implemented:

1. `head` represents the first element of a `List`, so it would not make sense to create a function to iterate over all heads are there is only one. Then why not a function `prefixes`?
2. It is not possible to make this function tail recursive so we prefer to ignore it.
3. It is useless (is it?)
4. It is not compatible with the philosophy of functional programming (why?)

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Would heads be the list itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for inits.

head = first element
last = last element
tail = all except head
tails = recurses tail
init = all except last
inits = recurses init

See the descriptions under trait Traversable in the [Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html).

Comment: Thanks for this great summary. I didn't "see" inits in the documentation.

Comment: +1, I couldn't find `inits` in the link provided, but it is currently defined in `TraversableLike` - see the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike)